# Changing the glyphicons on active tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, glyphicons

So I'm using the bootstrap on my website and I want to show a small glyph icons next to the tabs but I want the glyph icons to change n the active tab. as you can see on the picture, right now all tabs have the same icon but I want the icon on the active tab to change to something else. what is the best way to do this?

Thank you

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills outline" id="prodtabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title active outline"><a href="#tabprodesc" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">product description<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title outline"><a href="#tabdetail" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">detail specification <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title outline"><a href="#tabreviews" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">reviews <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></li>

  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I forgot. it's done now

Comment: If you want the solution using only html/css or bootstrap then I'm sorry but it's just not possible. You will need to use JavaScript or something similar.

Comment: I do have some knowledge of JS but now enough to know what exactly should I do for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an HTML/CSS solution, then this is what you need to do:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills outline" id="prodtabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title active outline"><a href="#tabprodesc" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">product description<i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title outline"><a href="#tabdetail" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">detail specification <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="tab-title outline"><a href="#tabreviews" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">reviews <i class="fa"></i></a></li>

  </ul>
```

I removed the class that loads the glyph. 
Now add this css:

```
ul.nav-pills li.tab-title i.fa:before {
    content: "\f107";
}
ul.nav-pills li.active i.fa:before {
    content: "\f005";
}
```

This solution does require some changes to the HTML. You have to remove the class that loads the glyph and load a different one depending on whether the tab element is active or not.

Comment: Can I just say: Thank you so much! this is just amazing! I never though something like this is possible with CSS! thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you want the solution using only HTML/CSS or Bootstrap then I'm sorry but it's just not possible. You will need to use JavaScript or something similar.

The following is a jQuery code sample that changes the class of the item with the fa-angle-down as soon as the page loads. Not an exact solution but I hope you can work your way up from here?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-twitter');
$('.fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
});
</script>
```